# Overwritting dictionary 'update' method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, subclassing

I am trying to subclass `dict` to modify its `update` method.

The behavior I am looking for is to add the values of common keys and keep the unique ones.

## Example:

```
g1 = MyDict({1: 1, 2: 2})
g2 = MyDict({1: 1, 3: 3})
g1.update(g2)  # should result in g1 = {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3}
#                                          ^ because it is 1 from g1 + 1 from g2
```

---

in other words, as if I was doing:

```
from collections import Counter
g1 =  dict(Counter(g1) + Counter(g2))
```

For this task, I wrote the following:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __update__(self, d2):
        keys = set(self).union(d2)
        self = {k: self.get(k, 0) + d2.get(k, 0) for k in keys}
        return
```

but when doing:

```
g1 = MyDict({1: 1, 2: 2})
g2 = MyDict({1: 1, 3: 3})
g1.update(g2)
```

it produces:

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

However, if I do:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __add__(self, d2):
        keys = set(self).union(d2)
        return {k: self.get(k, 0) + d2.get(k, 0) for k in keys}
```

and then

```
g1 = g1 + g2
```

the desired behavior is implemented..

What am I doing wrong when overwriting the `update` method?

Comment: You're defining the `__update__` method, but you're calling the `update` method. Also `__update__` doesn't modify the dict at all, it just returns a new value (which doesn't do anything here).

Comment: @deceze Sorry, copy-paste error. Take another look please.

Comment: Change `def __update__(self, d2):` to `def update(self, d2):`

Comment: Still the same `update` vs. `__update__` problem. It works with `__add__` because `+` implicitly calls `__add__`. But `update` does not implicitly call `__update__`, because why would it? Also, assigning to `self` doesn't do much; `self` is just a local variable in the method.

Comment: @deceze Oops, I thought that doing `dct.update(..)` calls the `__update__` function. My bad. Can you post an answer?

Comment: @CarlosMermingas this change alone does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following way to do it:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def update(self, d2):
        for k in set(self).union(d2):
            self[k] = self.get(k, 0) + d2.get(k, 0)
        return
```

which indeed, when doing:

```
g1 = MyDict({1: 1, 2: 2})
g2 = MyDict({1: 1, 3: 3})
g1.update(g2)
```

results in:

```
print(g1)  # -> {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

---

If there is a better way, let me know.

Thanks for the comments!